# Attach 2 lines or text files in one

Tags: php, regex, text, notepad++

I have:

First text file:

```
Mark

Jon 

Brik
```

And a second text file:

```
Davdiosn

smith

gick
```

I want to make them like:

```
Mark Davodison

Jon Smith

Brick Grick
```

How can I do this?

Comment: think about it, try it, post your code. This is SO.

Comment: @michi - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Comment: @PédeLeão ok, I agree, can be understood as unfriendly, though it wasn't meant to be. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

1. first put all texts from file one in to an array1
2. then do the same with second file and put all the values in array2

then use array_splice

Comment: heh, he even tagged the question as `php` :)

Answer (score 0):

Load the files to array using `file` and filter spaces using `array_filter`

```
$a = array_filter(file("a.log"));
$b = array_filter(file("b.log"));
```

You can use `array_map`

```
foreach(array_map(null, $a, $b) as $name) {
    echo implode(" ", array_map("trim",$name)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or `MultipleIterator`

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($a));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($b));

foreach($mi as $name) {
    echo implode(" ", array_map("trim", $name)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
Mark Davdiosn

Jon smith

Brik gick
```

Answer (score 0):

With the combination of Column Select and Regular Expressions you can achieve this in Notepad++.

- Open the second file.
- Keeping the cursor at the beginning, press Shift + Alt and use down arrow key to go to the last line. Then use the right arrow key as many times to select all the contents.
- Ctrl + C to copy the contents.
- Open the first file.
- Append spaces at the end of the first line so that it is the longest line in the file.
- Keep the cursor at the end of the first line and paste the contents Ctrl + V

Now the file should look something like this,

```
Mark Davdiosn

Jon  smith

Brik gick
```

You might see more that one space between words in some lines.

- Now use Find/Replace feature.
- Select Regex Search Mode.
- In Find box enter this `( ){2,}`
- In Replace box enter this `( )`

Now you have the file as you wanted it.

```
Mark Davdiosn

Jon smith

Brik gick
```

Cheers..